# Failed to configure a DataSource: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: spring

09:13:42.160 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@4c2a545c

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.8)

2023-02-20 09:13:42.672  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.bookingdemo.BookingdemoApplication   : Starting BookingdemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_361 on LAPTOP-I98TF32A with PID 13192 (C:\Users\rutvi\Downloads\bookingdemo\bookingdemo\target\classes started by rutvij in C:\Users\rutvi\Downloads\bookingdemo\bookingdemo)
2023-02-20 09:13:42.676  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.bookingdemo.BookingdemoApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-20 09:13:42.814  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-02-20 09:13:42.814  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-02-20 09:13:44.069  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-02-20 09:13:44.099  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 12 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-02-20 09:13:45.621  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-20 09:13:45.642  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-20 09:13:45.642  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.71]
2023-02-20 09:13:45.901  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-20 09:13:45.902  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3087 ms
2023-02-20 09:13:46.039  WARN 13192 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-02-20 09:13:46.042  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-02-20 09:13:46.080  INFO 13192 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-20 09:13:46.126 ERROR 13192 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: Did you set up the DB? I can see that your workspace is in Downloads directory and wondering if you have set-up the DB. If you have, then did you provide `spring.datasource.url=...` in your properties file?

Comment: Yes I did and the issue was eclipse couldn't  determine the port

Comment: Specify the correct datasource url in the properties/yaml file, where your Database is running:
Assuming it's a MySQL DB, the format should be:
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:{port}/{db_name}`
The default port is `3306`.


e.g. If you are running locally on the default port and trying to access DB named yourDatabaseName then, it should be :
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabaseName`


Refer documentation: [Accessing data with MySQL](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/)